# angularjs get only selected checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

i want to get the selected checkboxes in my loop, for that check box i have to retrive the amount field onclick.

**Here is my HTML script :**

```
<div ng-repeat="$item in items">
    Amount  :<input ng-model="$item.daily_data.payment_amount">
    Check  : <input type=checkbox ng-model="checkAmount[$item.daily_data.id]" ng-value="$item.id" >
</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="checkNow()" />
```

The below script showing all check boxes . i want the only selected one.

**JS Script :**

```
$scope.checkAmount = {};
$scope.checkNow(){
console.log($scope.checkAmount);
}
```

Comment: Are you inside `ngRepeat`?

Comment: Yes. inside ngRepeat

Comment: Updated the question, hope you can see the modification. any solution.?

Comment: Yes, see my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all to use `functions` with `$scope` you should do something like this:

```
$scope.checkNow = function() {
  ...
}
```

or

```
$scope.checkNow = checkNow;

function checkNow() {
  ...
}
```

About your problem:

You could bind the `checkboxes` to a *property* (something like `checked`), so you can have the items that are `checked` easily in your `controller`.

Then, to calculate the *total* of all **checked** amount , I' suggest you to use [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [**`Array.prototype.reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Here's a **demo** based on your *original* `code`:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.checkNow = checkNow;
    $scope.checkAmount = {};
    $scope.items = [
      {
        "id": 1
      }, 
      {
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ];

    function checkNow() {
      $scope.total = $scope.items.filter(function(value) {
        return value.checked;
      }).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b.amount;
      }, 0);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="$item in items">
    <label>
      Amount: <input type="number" ng-model="$item.amount">
    </label>
    <label>
      Check: <input type=checkbox ng-model="$item.checked">
    </label>
  </div>

  <button type="button" ng-click="checkNow()">Check now</button>
  <hr>
  <label for="total">Total</label>
  <input type="number" id="total" disabled ng-model="total">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if My Amount and id at this Level the `$item.daily_data.payment_amount`.

Comment: I didn't understand.. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, i will do that. give me a minute please.

Comment: i did changes the amount and id field model. which are used in my application. can you please do the same changes in your Answer.

Comment: Its giving 0 total result for me.

Comment: What? I didn't understand what do you mean by "*i did changes the amount and id field model. which are used in my application"*. Well, it works, as you want, only the **checked** amounts are count...

Comment: i mean in my question i have replace item.id with $item.daily_data.id which i have in my application. hope you understand.

Comment: But I'm not using any `id` here in my solution, You don't need any id or ng-value. Just see above.

Comment: Thanks For your Time. Your Solution is Really Helpful.

Comment: Hi @developer033, i have a submit button out side the loop. i want to enable that when checkbox is selected and amount is grater that 0. can you suggest a solution.?

Comment: Hello, @MohammadFareed, I would suggest you to create another question with this new content..